# CountDownTimer for Android

Tags: android, timer

I have a `CountDownTimer` that I want to display a count from next two weeks, which should start count down from `13d:00h:00:59s`. However the following piece of code gives me a result I don't understand.

`354h:16m:59s`

Here is my code.

```
public class CounterClass1 extends CountDownTimer {

    public CounterClass1(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    diffDays.setText("League finishes in: " +    
        String.format("%02dd:%02dh:%02dm:%02ds",

        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(millisUntilFinished),

        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished) - 
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(

        TimeUnit.DAYS.toDays(millisUntilFinished)),
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) -  
        TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(

        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),

        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -  
        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(

        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        //diffDays.setText("Completed");
    }
}
```

Any advice would really be helpful.

Thanks,
Theo.

Comment: `DAYS.toDays` gives you the number of days represented by that many days. (i.e. it returns the input)

Answer (score 0):

You're just doing the conversions wrong it seems..

```
int days = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(millisUntilFinished);
int hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)
        - TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours(days);
int minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECOND.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)
        - ( TimeUnit.DAYS.toMinutes(days) + TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(hours));
int seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECOND.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished)
        - ( TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(days) + TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(hours) + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(minutes));

String.format("%02dd:%02dh:%02dm:%02ds", days, hours, minutes, seconds));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am trying to change that.